# Authentication in Kamailio Registration

Tags: registration, sip, kamailio

I am running **Kamailio Server** on cloud instance . The domain name of the server is well above 55 bytes . When I enable Authentication in kamailio server (after adding users ), I find that my client has issues in providing **Authentication information during registration** since the REALM field has **value greater than 55 bytes**.

So, is there any way that I can reduce the REALM value published by the Kamailio server in **its 401 response**.

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 2):

The **realm** value is a parameter to the functions exported by auth or auth_db modules. With default kamailio.cfg, the real is taken from From header domain. But you can change that to what you want, provided that is unique for your service.

For example, using the realm **myservice.com**:

```
if (!auth_check("myservice.com", "subscriber", "1")) {
    auth_challenge("myservice.com", "0");
    exit;
}
```